# A question on Radon-Nikodym derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

I t that there are functions continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere.Then let c(t) be one of them. And let μ[t1,t2]=c(t2)-c(t1). So in this case c(t) is not differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a more advanced course in measure theory you will learn that **monotone** functions are automatically differentiable almost everywhere with respect to the Lebesgue measure. This of course covers cumulative distributions.